# cannot update field on Change

Tags: reactjs

i have 3 update textfields, the value of which is coming from a state called edit_obj, like so:

```
<input type="text" noValidate name="uname_edit" value={this.state.edit_obj.username} onChange={e => this.editchangeHandler(e)} />
```

when i click on 'edit' button, `editClick` function works that sets the value of `edit_obj` like so:

`this.setState({edit_obj: editval})`

I am attaching the full code. Please let me know how i can edit the value d the textfield:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FromErrors1} from './formErrors';
import { SlowBuffer } from 'buffer';




class Form extends React.Component{

 constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state={
  uname: '',
  pass: '',
  address:'',
  salary:'',
  addFormValues:{
    username:'',
    password:'',
    address:''
  },
  errorfields:{
    uname_err:'',
    pass_err:'',
    address_err:'',
    salary_err:'',
    valid_user:false,
    valid_pass:false,
    valid_address:false,
    valid_salary:false,
  },
  delete_data:[],
  edit_showui:false,
  edit_obj:{},
  editval:{},
  edit_data:[],
  editted_uname:''
}
this.changeHandler= this.changeHandler.bind(this)
this.pushAddStudentData=new Array()
this.submitForm= this.submitForm.bind(this);
//this.editchangeHandler = this.editchangeHandler.bind(this)
//this.editClick = this.editClick.bind(this)
 }

 editClick =(that,editval) =>{
   //alert("du")
  //show edit ui:
   this.setState({edit_showui:true});

//add values to the inputs of show ui
console.log('editval: ',editval);
//this.setState({edit_obj:editval});
//this.setState({edit_data:this.state.edit_data.push(editval)});
/*this.setState((state)=>({
  edit_data:state.edit_data.push(editval)
}))*/
this.state.edit_data=[]


this.setState(prevState => ({
  edit_data: [...prevState.edit_data, editval]
}))
this.setState({edit_obj: editval})
console.log("edit_obj:::::::",this.state.edit_obj)
 }

 editchangeHandler = (e) =>{
  console.log('ename::',e.target.name)
  console.log('etarget::',e.target.value)
//this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
 console.log('edit_obj::',this.state.edit_obj)

//newEditVal
//this.state.newEditVal.username = 
/*
if(e.target.name=='uname_edit'){
  console.log('uname_edit')
  //editted_uname
  this.setState(
    {editted_uname : ''}
)

console.log('editted_uname::',this.state.editted_uname)
  } 



if(e.target.name=='pass_edit'){
  console.log('pass_edit')
  }
  if(e.target.name=='address_edit'){
    console.log('address_edit')
    }
 */
//this.setState({})
this.setState({
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
});

}

 updateval=()=>{
console.log('EDIT_OBJ: ',this.state.edit_obj)
 }

 deleteClick =(e,f) =>{

   console.log("sefr",e,'a::',f);



// if(this.pushAddStudentData.indexOf(f) > -1){

// }
let finaldeleteddata=[];
for( var i = 0; i < this.state.delete_data.length; i++){
  console.log('this.state.delete_data[i]===f:: ',this.state.delete_data[i]===f)

  console.log('and f:: ',f)
  if ( this.state.delete_data[i] === f) {
    this.state.delete_data.splice(i, 1);



    // this.setState(
    //   {
    //   delete_data:finaldeleteddata
    //   }
    //  )   
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      delete_data: [...prevState.delete_data]
  }))


  }

  console.log('YEYEYEYEEDITDATATAa:: ',this.state.delete_data) 
  console.log("finaldeleteddata:: ",finaldeleteddata)

}



}
 changeHandler = (ev) =>{

 // alert("gugugu")
this.setState({[ev.target.name]:ev.target.value})
console.log(this.state)
 }


 submitForm = (e) =>{
let finaladdeddata;
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('this.state.uname:',this.state.uname);
  console.log('this.state.pass:',this.state.pass);


let usererror = {...this.state.errorfields};
var regex_username = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/);

if(this.state.uname && regex_username.test(this.state.uname)){
    //no error
   // this.state.valid_user= true;  /THIS IS NOT RIGHT WAY, USE THIS.SETSTATE
   alert("iffff");

   usererror.uname_err='';
   usererror.valid_user = true
 console.log("usererror::",usererror)

   console.log("this.STATEuserif:::",this.state.errorfields.valid_user)
   this.setState({errorfields: usererror});


  }else{
    //else of user
    alert('2user')
    console.log('usererror: ',usererror)
    usererror.uname_err= 'username not valid';
    usererror.valid_user = false;

    this.setState({errorfields: usererror});

    //there is error
    console.log("this.STATEuserelse:::",this.state)
}



if(this.state.pass && this.state.pass.length <=6){
  //if of pass
  //no error
 // this.state.valid_pass= true;
 usererror.valid_pass=true;
 usererror.pass_err='';
 this.setState({errorfields:usererror})
 console.log("this.STATEpassif:::",this.state)
}else{
  //else of pass
  alert('2pass')
  usererror.valid_pass=false;
  usererror.pass_err='invalid password | password length more than 6';
  this.setState({errorfields:usererror})

  //there is error


console.log('this.state.errorfields',this.state.errorfields)
console.log("this.STATE2:::",this.state)
}
//usererror
//errorfields
console.log("address:", this.state.address)
console.log("salary:", this.state.salary)
//put error fields in address
if(this.state.address && this.state.address.length<=20){
 // this.state.valid_address=true;


usererror.address_err='';
usererror.valid_address=true
  this.setState({errorfields:usererror})
  } else{
    usererror.address_err='Empty address | address length more than 20';
    usererror.valid_address=false
    this.setState({errorfields:usererror})

}

/*form={}
  uname: '',
  pass: '',
  address:''
}*/

console.log('usererror.valid_address',usererror.valid_address);
console.log('usererror.valid_pass',usererror.valid_pass);
console.log('usererror.valid_user',usererror.valid_user);

if(usererror.valid_address==true && usererror.valid_pass==true && usererror.valid_user==true){
  alert("YESSS");
  let addFormValues_dupl= {...this.state.addFormValues};

  addFormValues_dupl.username = this.state.uname;
  addFormValues_dupl.password = this.state.pass;
  addFormValues_dupl.address = this.state.address;
  console.log('addFormValues_dupl',addFormValues_dupl);  
 // this.pushAddStudentData.push(addFormValues_dupl)
 //this.setState({delete_data:addFormValues_dupl})
this.state.delete_data.push(addFormValues_dupl)

 console.log('state',this.state);  
  // this.setState({addFormValues: this.state.uname})

}else{
  alert("NOOO")
  //this.pushAddStudentData=[]
  console.log('pushAddStudentDataELSE',this.pushAddStudentData[0]);  
}

 }

render(){

  return(

    <div>
<h2>Add Employee info</h2>
<div className="displayerrors">
{/* <ul>{this.state.errorfields.map((a,i)=>{<li>a</li>})}</ul> */}
<input type="hidden" value={this.state.errorfields}/>
<p>{this.state.errorfields.uname_err} - {this.state.errorfields.valid_user}</p>
<p>{this.state.errorfields.pass_err}</p>
<p>{this.state.errorfields.address_err}- {this.state.errorfields.valid_address}</p>
</div>

      <div>
        <label>username:</label>
        <input type="text" noValidate name="uname" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>password:</label>
        <input type="password" noValidate name="pass" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>address:</label>
        <textarea noValidate name="address" onChange={this.changeHandler}></textarea>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={this.submitForm}></button>
      </div>

      <div>{this.state.delete_data.length}
                {this.state.delete_data.map((a,i)=>{
               return <ul key={i}> <li>{i}</li><li>{a.username}</li> 
                <li>{a.password}</li>
               <li>{a.address}</li>
               <li><a href="#" onClick={()=>{this.deleteClick(this,a)}}>Delete</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" onClick={()=>{this.editClick(this,a)}}>Edit</a></li></ul>
                })}
            </div>
{  this.state.edit_showui==true && 
<div>

      <div>

        <label>username:</label>
        <input type="text" noValidate name="uname_edit" value={this.state.edit_obj.username} onChange={e => this.editchangeHandler(e)} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>password:</label>
        <input type="password" noValidate name="pass_edit" value={this.state.edit_obj.password} onChange={this.editchangeHandler.bind(this)} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>address:</label>
        <textarea noValidate name="address_edit" value={this.state.edit_obj.address} onChange={this.editchangeHandler.bind(this)}></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateval.bind(this)}>update</button>
      </div>

      <div>{this.state.edit_obj.username}</div>
      <div>{this.state.edit_obj.password}</div>
      <div>{this.state.edit_obj.address}</div>
</div>
}
editdata: 
<div>{this.state.edit_data.username}</div>
      <div>{this.state.edit_data.password}</div>
      <div>{this.state.edit_data.address}</div>
 {this.state.edit_data.map((q,i)=>{
                return <ul key={i}> <li>{i}</li><li>{q.username}</li> 
                 <li>{q.password}</li>
                <li>{q.address}</li>
              </ul>
                 })}
 }

    </div>

  )//return ends

}


}

export default Form;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example!

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve? Do you want to change the value of text fields as soon as the value in them changes?

Comment: i want that when i click on the Update button, the value i changed in textfield upadates. But that is a later stage, because i am not able to change field value in the first place.